# Call .js file in UpdatePanel from CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, code-behind

I am have been trying to teach myself ASP.NET and Javascript for a project and have been stuck on one problem for literally dozens of hours now.

I found a really nice javascript drag-and-drop list online, copied the source offered and split the css into a .css file, the javascript into a .js file and the HTML and  reference into my asp.net page. It worked perfectly. Great!

Next, I replaced the javascript list with a static HTML list populated with the same data, wrapped it in an UpdatePanel and set up an "edit order" button to swap the static list's HTML for the javascript list's HTML when the button is pressed.

No Dice!

First, the initial runtime would throw up javascript errors explaining that certain objects could not be found. For example:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'getElementsByTagName': object is null or undefined
```

Understood, because the elements aren't actually there yet. So I removed my reference to the .js in the main header and tried to register the .js file when the update panel is changed instead.

This is my problem.

Most explanations online have focused onRegisterClientScriptBlock, or RegisterStartupScript, or RegisterClientScriptInclude, or myLiteral and I can't get any of them to work. I also find that lots of online explanations are for running a single javascript function, whereas the script I am trying to get working has 700 lines-worth of them! Do I have to reference them all individually?

Sorry for the, no doubt, newbish question. I waited to ask until I had shouted at the screen with sufficient vitriol to warrant begging for help!

Thanks and regards.

EDIT: CODE

As Requested, this is the code:

VB.net (this is in a sub called by the button press. This is when I need to register my script)

```
    Dim script As String = ""

    Dim Labelb As Label = CType(FindControl("Labelb"), Label)


    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    con = New SqlConnection("[connection string here]")
    con.Open()
    Dim lrd As SqlDataReader

    cmd = New SqlCommand("[command string here]", con)
    lrd = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim item = ""



    While lrd.Read()
        item = item & "<li style=""position: relative;"">" & lrd(1) & "</li>"
    End While
    lrd.Close()

    item = "<table id=""phonetics""><tbody><tr><td><ul id=""phonetic3"" class=""boxy"">" & item & "</ul></td></tr></tbody></table><br/>"


    Labelb.Text = item
```

This is the HTML update panel in the asp.net master page:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Labelb" runat="server" Text="" />

                            </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and finally, this is the .js file that I need to register

```
var ToolMan = {
events : function() {
if (!ToolMan._eventsFactory) throw "ToolMan Events module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._eventsFactory
},

css : function() {
if (!ToolMan._cssFactory) throw "ToolMan CSS module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._cssFactory
},

coordinates : function() {
if (!ToolMan._coordinatesFactory) throw "ToolMan Coordinates module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._coordinatesFactory
},

drag : function() {
if (!ToolMan._dragFactory) throw "ToolMan Drag module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._dragFactory
},

dragsort : function() {
if (!ToolMan._dragsortFactory) throw "ToolMan DragSort module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._dragsortFactory
},

helpers : function() {
return ToolMan._helpers
},

cookies : function() {
if (!ToolMan._cookieOven) throw "ToolMan Cookie module isn't loaded";
return ToolMan._cookieOven
},

junkdrawer : function() {
return ToolMan._junkdrawer
}

}

ToolMan._helpers = {
map : function(array, func) {
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) func(array[i])
},

nextItem : function(item, nodeName) {
if (item == null) return
var next = item.nextSibling
while (next != null) {
if (next.nodeName == nodeName) return next
next = next.nextSibling
}
return null
},

previousItem : function(item, nodeName) {
var previous = item.previousSibling
while (previous != null) {
if (previous.nodeName == nodeName) return previous
previous = previous.previousSibling
}
return null
},

moveBefore : function(item1, item2) {
var parent = item1.parentNode
parent.removeChild(item1)
parent.insertBefore(item1, item2)
},

moveAfter : function(item1, item2) {
var parent = item1.parentNode
parent.removeChild(item1)
parent.insertBefore(item1, item2 ? item2.nextSibling : null)
}
}

/** 
* scripts without a proper home
*
* stuff here is subject to change unapologetically and without warning
*/
ToolMan._junkdrawer = {
serializeList : function(list) {
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li")
var array = new Array()
for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
var item = items[i]

array.push(ToolMan.junkdrawer()._identifier(item))
}
return array.join('|')
},

inspectListOrder : function(id) {
alert(ToolMan.junkdrawer().serializeList(document.getElementById(id)))
},

restoreListOrder : function(listID) {
var list = document.getElementById(listID)
if (list == null) return

var cookie = ToolMan.cookies().get("list-" + listID)
if (!cookie) return;

var IDs = cookie.split('|')
var items = ToolMan.junkdrawer()._itemsByID(list)

for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i < n; i++) {
  var itemID = IDs[i]
  if (itemID in items) {
    var item = items[itemID]
    list.removeChild(item)
    list.insertBefore(item, null)
  }
}
},

_identifier : function(item) {
var trim = ToolMan.junkdrawer().trim
var identifier

identifier = trim(item.getAttribute("id"))
if (identifier != null && identifier.length > 0) return identifier;

identifier = trim(item.getAttribute("itemID"))
if (identifier != null && identifier.length > 0) return identifier;

// FIXME: strip out special chars or make this an MD5 hash or something
return trim(item.innerHTML)
},

_itemsByID : function(list) {
var array = new Array()
var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li')
for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
  var item = items[i]
  array[ToolMan.junkdrawer()._identifier(item)] = item
}
return array
},

trim : function(text) {
if (text == null) return null
return text.replace(/^(\s+)?(.*\S)(\s+)?$/, '$2')
}
}


ToolMan._eventsFactory = {
fix : function(event) {
if (!event) event = window.event

if (event.target) {
  if (event.target.nodeType == 3) event.target = event.target.parentNode
} else if (event.srcElement) {
  event.target = event.srcElement
}

return event
},

 register : function(element, type, func) {
if (element.addEventListener) {
  element.addEventListener(type, func, false)
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
  if (!element._listeners) element._listeners = new Array()
  if (!element._listeners[type]) element._listeners[type] = new Array()
  var workaroundFunc = function() {
    func.apply(element, new Array())
  }
  element._listeners[type][func] = workaroundFunc
  element.attachEvent('on' + type, workaroundFunc)
  }
  },

unregister : function(element, type, func) {
if (element.removeEventListener) {
  element.removeEventListener(type, func, false)
} else if (element.detachEvent) {
  if (element._listeners 
      && element._listeners[type] 
      && element._listeners[type][func]) {

    element.detachEvent('on' + type, 
        element._listeners[type][func])
  }
 }
  }
 }


ToolMan._cssFactory = {
readStyle : function(element, property) {
if (element.style[property]) {
  return element.style[property]
} else if (element.currentStyle) {
  return element.currentStyle[property]
} else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
  var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null)
  return style.getPropertyValue(property)
} else {
  return null
}
}
}




/* FIXME: assumes position styles are specified in 'px' */

ToolMan._coordinatesFactory = {

create : function(x, y) {
// FIXME: Safari won't parse 'throw' and aborts trying to do anything with this file
//if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) throw "invalid x,y: " + x + "," + y
return new _ToolManCoordinate(this, x, y)
},

origin : function() {
return this.create(0, 0)
},

/*
 * FIXME: Safari 1.2, returns (0,0) on absolutely positioned elements
 */
topLeftPosition : function(element) {
var left = parseInt(ToolMan.css().readStyle(element, "left"))
var left = isNaN(left) ? 0 : left
var top = parseInt(ToolMan.css().readStyle(element, "top"))
var top = isNaN(top) ? 0 : top

return this.create(left, top)
},

bottomRightPosition : function(element) {
return this.topLeftPosition(element).plus(this._size(element))
},

topLeftOffset : function(element) {
var offset = this._offset(element) 

var parent = element.offsetParent
while (parent) {
  offset = offset.plus(this._offset(parent))
  parent = parent.offsetParent
}
 return offset
},

bottomRightOffset : function(element) {
return this.topLeftOffset(element).plus(
    this.create(element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight))
},

scrollOffset : function() {
if (window.pageXOffset) {
  return this.create(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset)
} else if (document.documentElement) {
  return this.create(
      document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft, 
      document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop)
} else if (document.body.scrollLeft >= 0) {
  return this.create(document.body.scrollLeft, document.body.scrollTop)
} else {
  return this.create(0, 0)
}
},

clientSize : function() {
if (window.innerHeight >= 0) {
  return this.create(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
} else if (document.documentElement) {
  return this.create(document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      document.documentElement.clientHeight)
} else if (document.body.clientHeight >= 0) {
  return this.create(document.body.clientWidth,
      document.body.clientHeight)
} else {
  return this.create(0, 0)
}
},

/**
 * mouse coordinate relative to the window (technically the
 * browser client area) i.e. the part showing your page
 *
 * NOTE: in Safari the coordinate is relative to the document
 */
 mousePosition : function(event) {
 event = ToolMan.events().fix(event)
 return this.create(event.clientX, event.clientY)
},

 /**
 * mouse coordinate relative to the document
 */
mouseOffset : function(event) {
event = ToolMan.events().fix(event)
if (event.pageX >= 0 || event.pageX < 0) {
  return this.create(event.pageX, event.pageY)
} else if (event.clientX >= 0 || event.clientX < 0) {
  return this.mousePosition(event).plus(this.scrollOffset())
}
},

_size : function(element) {
/* TODO: move to a Dimension class */
 return this.create(element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight)
},

_offset : function(element) {
return this.create(element.offsetLeft, element.offsetTop)
}
}

function _ToolManCoordinate(factory, x, y) {
this.factory = factory
this.x = isNaN(x) ? 0 : x
this.y = isNaN(y) ? 0 : y
}

_ToolManCoordinate.prototype = {
toString : function() {
return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")"
},

plus : function(that) {
return this.factory.create(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
},

minus : function(that) {
return this.factory.create(this.x - that.x, this.y - that.y)
},

min : function(that) {
return this.factory.create(
    Math.min(this.x , that.x), Math.min(this.y , that.y))
},

max : function(that) {
return this.factory.create(
    Math.max(this.x , that.x), Math.max(this.y , that.y))
 },

constrainTo : function (one, two) {
var min = one.min(two)
var max = one.max(two)

return this.max(min).min(max)
},

distance : function (that) {
 return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - that.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - that.y, 2))
},

reposition : function(element) {
element.style["top"] = this.y + "px"
element.style["left"] = this.x + "px"
}
}



ToolMan._dragFactory = {
createSimpleGroup : function(element, handle) {
handle = handle ? handle : element
var group = this.createGroup(element)
group.setHandle(handle)
group.transparentDrag()
group.onTopWhileDragging()
return group
},

createGroup : function(element) {
var group = new _ToolManDragGroup(this, element)

var position = ToolMan.css().readStyle(element, 'position')
if (position == 'static') {
  element.style["position"] = 'relative'
} else if (position == 'absolute') {
  /* for Safari 1.2 */
  ToolMan.coordinates().topLeftOffset(element).reposition(element)
}

// TODO: only if ToolMan.isDebugging()
group.register('draginit', this._showDragEventStatus)
group.register('dragmove', this._showDragEventStatus)
group.register('dragend', this._showDragEventStatus)

return group
},

_showDragEventStatus : function(dragEvent) {
window.status = dragEvent.toString()
},

constraints : function() {
return this._constraintFactory
},

_createEvent : function(type, event, group) {
return new _ToolManDragEvent(type, event, group)
}
}

function _ToolManDragGroup(factory, element) {
this.factory = factory
this.element = element
this._handle = null
this._thresholdDistance = 0
this._transforms = new Array()
// TODO: refactor into a helper object, move into events.js
this._listeners = new Array()
this._listeners['draginit'] = new Array()
this._listeners['dragstart'] = new Array()
this._listeners['dragmove'] = new Array()
this._listeners['dragend'] = new Array()
}

_ToolManDragGroup.prototype = {
/*
 * TODO:
 *   - unregister(type, func)
  *   - move custom event listener stuff into Event library
 *   - keyboard nudging of "selected" group
 */

setHandle : function(handle) {
var events = ToolMan.events()

handle.toolManDragGroup = this
events.register(handle, 'mousedown', this._dragInit)
handle.onmousedown = function() { return false }

if (this.element != handle)
  events.unregister(this.element, 'mousedown', this._dragInit)
},

register : function(type, func) {
 this._listeners[type].push(func)
},

addTransform : function(transformFunc) {
this._transforms.push(transformFunc)
},

verticalOnly : function() {
this.addTransform(this.factory.constraints().vertical())
},

horizontalOnly : function() {
this.addTransform(this.factory.constraints().horizontal())
},

setThreshold : function(thresholdDistance) {
this._thresholdDistance = thresholdDistance
},

transparentDrag : function(opacity) {
var opacity = typeof(opacity) != "undefined" ? opacity : 0.75;
var originalOpacity = ToolMan.css().readStyle(this.element, "opacity")

this.register('dragstart', function(dragEvent) {
  var element = dragEvent.group.element
  element.style.opacity = opacity
  element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (opacity * 100) + ')'
})
this.register('dragend', function(dragEvent) {
  var element = dragEvent.group.element
  element.style.opacity = originalOpacity
  element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)'
})
},

onTopWhileDragging : function(zIndex) {
var zIndex = typeof(zIndex) != "undefined" ? zIndex : 100000;
var originalZIndex = ToolMan.css().readStyle(this.element, "z-index")

this.register('dragstart', function(dragEvent) {
  dragEvent.group.element.style.zIndex = zIndex
})
this.register('dragend', function(dragEvent) {
  dragEvent.group.element.style.zIndex = originalZIndex
})
},

_dragInit : function(event) {
event = ToolMan.events().fix(event)
var group = document.toolManDragGroup = this.toolManDragGroup
var dragEvent = group.factory._createEvent('draginit', event, group)

group._isThresholdExceeded = false
group._initialMouseOffset = dragEvent.mouseOffset
group._grabOffset = dragEvent.mouseOffset.minus(dragEvent.topLeftOffset)
ToolMan.events().register(document, 'mousemove', group._drag)
document.onmousemove = function() { return false }
ToolMan.events().register(document, 'mouseup', group._dragEnd)

group._notifyListeners(dragEvent)
},

_drag : function(event) {
event = ToolMan.events().fix(event)
var coordinates = ToolMan.coordinates()
var group = this.toolManDragGroup
if (!group) return
var dragEvent = group.factory._createEvent('dragmove', event, group)

var newTopLeftOffset = dragEvent.mouseOffset.minus(group._grabOffset)

// TODO: replace with DragThreshold object
if (!group._isThresholdExceeded) {
  var distance = 
      dragEvent.mouseOffset.distance(group._initialMouseOffset)
  if (distance < group._thresholdDistance) return
  group._isThresholdExceeded = true
  group._notifyListeners(
      group.factory._createEvent('dragstart', event, group))
}

for (i in group._transforms) {
  var transform = group._transforms[i]
  newTopLeftOffset = transform(newTopLeftOffset, dragEvent)
}

var dragDelta = newTopLeftOffset.minus(dragEvent.topLeftOffset)
var newTopLeftPosition = dragEvent.topLeftPosition.plus(dragDelta)
newTopLeftPosition.reposition(group.element)
dragEvent.transformedMouseOffset = newTopLeftOffset.plus(group._grabOffset)

group._notifyListeners(dragEvent)

var errorDelta = newTopLeftOffset.minus(coordinates.topLeftOffset(group.element))
if (errorDelta.x != 0 || errorDelta.y != 0) {
  coordinates.topLeftPosition(group.element).plus(errorDelta).reposition(group.element)
}
},

_dragEnd : function(event) {
event = ToolMan.events().fix(event)
var group = this.toolManDragGroup
var dragEvent = group.factory._createEvent('dragend', event, group)

group._notifyListeners(dragEvent)

this.toolManDragGroup = null
ToolMan.events().unregister(document, 'mousemove', group._drag)
document.onmousemove = null
ToolMan.events().unregister(document, 'mouseup', group._dragEnd)
},

_notifyListeners : function(dragEvent) {
var listeners = this._listeners[dragEvent.type]
for (i in listeners) {
  listeners[i](dragEvent)
}
}
}

function _ToolManDragEvent(type, event, group) {
this.type = type
this.group = group
this.mousePosition = ToolMan.coordinates().mousePosition(event)
this.mouseOffset = ToolMan.coordinates().mouseOffset(event)
this.transformedMouseOffset = this.mouseOffset
this.topLeftPosition = ToolMan.coordinates().topLeftPosition(group.element)
this.topLeftOffset = ToolMan.coordinates().topLeftOffset(group.element)
}

_ToolManDragEvent.prototype = {
toString : function() {
return "mouse: " + this.mousePosition + this.mouseOffset + "    " +
    "xmouse: " + this.transformedMouseOffset + "    " +
    "left,top: " + this.topLeftPosition + this.topLeftOffset
}
}

ToolMan._dragFactory._constraintFactory = {
vertical : function() {
return function(coordinate, dragEvent) {
  var x = dragEvent.topLeftOffset.x
  return coordinate.x != x
      ? coordinate.factory.create(x, coordinate.y) 
      : coordinate
}
},

horizontal : function() {
return function(coordinate, dragEvent) {
  var y = dragEvent.topLeftOffset.y
  return coordinate.y != y
      ? coordinate.factory.create(coordinate.x, y) 
      : coordinate
}
}
}


ToolMan._dragsortFactory = {
makeSortable : function(item) {
var group = ToolMan.drag().createSimpleGroup(item)

group.register('dragstart', this._onDragStart)
group.register('dragmove', this._onDragMove)
group.register('dragend', this._onDragEnd)

return group
},

/** 
 * Iterates over a list's items, making them sortable, applying
 * optional functions to each item.
 *
 * example: makeListSortable(myList, myFunc1, myFunc2, ... , myFuncN)
 */
 makeListSortable : function(list) {
var helpers = ToolMan.helpers()
var coordinates = ToolMan.coordinates()
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li")

helpers.map(items, function(item) {
  var dragGroup = dragsort.makeSortable(item)
  dragGroup.setThreshold(4)
  var min, max
  dragGroup.addTransform(function(coordinate, dragEvent) {
    return coordinate.constrainTo(min, max)
  })
  dragGroup.register('dragstart', function() {
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li")
    min = max = coordinates.topLeftOffset(items[0])
    for (var i = 1, n = items.length; i < n; i++) {
      var offset = coordinates.topLeftOffset(items[i])
      min = min.min(offset)
      max = max.max(offset)
    }
  })
})
for (var i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++)
  helpers.map(items, arguments[i])
},

_onDragStart : function(dragEvent) {
},

_onDragMove : function(dragEvent) {
var helpers = ToolMan.helpers()
var coordinates = ToolMan.coordinates()

var item = dragEvent.group.element
var xmouse = dragEvent.transformedMouseOffset
var moveTo = null

var previous = helpers.previousItem(item, item.nodeName)
while (previous != null) {
  var bottomRight = coordinates.bottomRightOffset(previous)
  if (xmouse.y <= bottomRight.y && xmouse.x <= bottomRight.x) {
    moveTo = previous
  }
  previous = helpers.previousItem(previous, item.nodeName)
}
if (moveTo != null) {
  helpers.moveBefore(item, moveTo)
  return
}

var next = helpers.nextItem(item, item.nodeName)
while (next != null) {
  var topLeft = coordinates.topLeftOffset(next)
  if (topLeft.y <= xmouse.y && topLeft.x <= xmouse.x) {
    moveTo = next
  }
  next = helpers.nextItem(next, item.nodeName)
}
if (moveTo != null) {
  helpers.moveBefore(item, helpers.nextItem(moveTo, item.nodeName))
  return
 }
},

_onDragEnd : function(dragEvent) {
ToolMan.coordinates().create(0, 0).reposition(dragEvent.group.element)
}
}


ToolMan._cookieOven = {

set : function(name, value, expirationInDays) {
if (expirationInDays) {
  var date = new Date()
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expirationInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
  var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString()
} else {
  var expires = ""
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"
},

get : function(name) {
var namePattern = name + "="
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
for(var i = 0, n = cookies.length; i < n; i++) {
  var c = cookies[i]
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length)
  if (c.indexOf(namePattern) == 0)
    return c.substring(namePattern.length, c.length)
}
return null
},

eraseCookie : function(name) {
createCookie(name, "", -1)
}
}


var dragsort = ToolMan.dragsort()
var junkdrawer = ToolMan.junkdrawer()

window.onload = function() {

junkdrawer.restoreListOrder("phonetic3")

//junkdrawer.restoreListOrder("twolists1")
//junkdrawer.restoreListOrder("twolists2")

dragsort.makeListSortable(document.getElementById("phonetic3"),
    verticalOnly, saveOrder)


/*
dragsort.makeListSortable(document.getElementById("twolists1"),
    saveOrder)
dragsort.makeListSortable(document.getElementById("twolists2"),
    saveOrder)
*/
}

function verticalOnly(item) {
item.toolManDragGroup.verticalOnly()
}

function speak(id, what) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.innerHTML = 'Clicked ' + what;
}

function saveOrder(item) {
var group = item.toolManDragGroup
var list = group.element.parentNode
var id = list.getAttribute("id")
if (id == null) return
group.register('dragend', function() {
  ToolMan.cookies().set("list-" + id, 
      junkdrawer.serializeList(list), 365)
})
}

//-->
```

Thanks so much for your support!

Regards,

Comment: Why not just include your .js ?

Comment: Because if I load at runtime it shows errors, and I cant figure out how to load it on an updatepanel change

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing `"value of the property 'getElementsByTagName'  object is null or undefined"` there is one of two possible issues:

```
1) your script file is not properly loaded.
2) You are calling  'getElementsByTagName' inappropriately.
```

Since you haven't posted any sample code, it would be very difficult for anybody to provide a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I am sure it is because my script file is not properly loaded. I will post my code.